# How to create a simple xml doc like this one

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am wanting to create an xml doc that looks like this but I don't know how to:

```
<bo type="Employee" id="0000012f41bce2a865f8616b0010007c0008008b">
  <username>marv</username>
</bo>
```

this is what I have so far, I'm really just confused as how to add the `username` element:

```
Element bo = testDoc.createElement("bo");
        bo.setAttribute("type", "Employee");
        bo.setAttribute("id", emp.getId());
```

Comment: Not really a good question, you can spend some time telling us more. Just reading the question itself, I would tell you to create it by copying it into a String (CTRL+C, CTRL+V). But that is not interesting, even it's a perfect answer to your very question. Please tell us something, it's in your interest. By the moment, -1 for this question.

Comment: @Giacomo Thanks for prompting me to make it more specific, it that better?

Comment: indeed. I removed my down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Element bo = testDoc.createElement("bo");
bo.setAttribute("type", "Employee");
bo.setAttribute("id", emp.getId());
//create a username element
Element username = testDoc.createElement("username");
//add a text value to the username element
username.appendChild(testDoc.createTextNode("marv"));
//add the username element as child of bo element
bo.appendChild(username);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a username element, set it's value, then make it a child of the bo element.  I don't know Java but there is probably an AddChild() method or similar you can use.